# $\mathbb{u,v,w}$ are vectors in 3 dimensional space-

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

$\mathbb{u,v,w}$ are vectors in 3 dimensional space. Under what restrictions on $c,d,e,$ will the combinations $c\mathbb{u} + d\mathbb{u} + e\mathbb{v}$ fill in the triangle formed by the heads of the vectors

---

I see that I get corners of the triangle when any two of $c,d,e$ are $0$ and making $c=d=e=1/3$ gives the centroid of triangle. How to find the remaining vectors that fill the triangle ?

Comment: Try answering the question in the two dimensional case first. Then use what you found for pairs of vectors like $u$ and $sv+tw$

Comment: they span the complete $xy$ plane right ? the problem is in restricting the variables such that a particular region is spanned

Comment: of course, if you consider $su+tv$ for arbitrary $s$ and $t$ you span the plane. What happens if you consider $s$ and $t$ such that $s+t=1$? Or $0\leq s+t \leq 1$?

Comment: $sv+tw = sv+(1-s)w = s(v-w) + w $ so they span a line which passes through the difference vector ?

Comment: I see what you're arriving at, but how do we extrapolate that to a region ? line is easy because I know parametric equations before. But the region thing is throwing me off

Comment: Exactly, they span a segment (remember we're considering $s\in[0,1]$) parallel to $(v-w)$ that passes through $w$! You're already there, what is this segment?

Comment: Oh do they span just the diagonal segment ? because making s=0 gives me $w$ and making t=0 gives me the other end $v$ ? awesome :3

Comment: does that work in 3D too ?  c+d+e=1 span just the triangle is it ? I still don't see it clearly but guess ill need to work it on paper

Comment: Yes, the condition $t+s=1$ guarantees $su+(1-s)v$ lies in the segment joining the endpoints of $u$ and $v$. This also holds in an arbitrary dimension! How could you reduce your 3D to a 2D problem?

Comment: $s(u-w) + t(v-w)$   such that  $0<s<1$ and $0<t<1$

Comment: im not sure if that fills the triangle, just cooked it up.. still working

Comment: You're already on the right track. You already know what you're supposed to get :P

Comment: lol been trying from yesterday but not really confident though, still exercising on taking combinations and seeing where they go. this is a hard problem for my level :o